# How to dynamically create zip archives from gatsby Directory nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, gatsby

I have a bunch of Directories that I am using as gatsby nodes and generating pages from these Directories like:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
query DosboxQuery {
  allDirectory(filter: {sourceInstanceName: {eq: "dosbox"} name: {ne: "dosbox"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        name
        dir
        modifiedTime
        children {
        __typename ... on File{
            name
            relativePath
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
  `)

  result.data.allDirectory.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    console.log("directory node", node);
    createPage({
      path: `/${node.name}/`,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/game-page.js`),
      context: {
        slug: `/${node.name}/`,
      },
    })
  })
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
}
```

I would like to generate `zip` archives of these Directories that users could download from the pages. I don't want to store or commit the `zip` archives because the content of the directories can change so I want to create the zip archives at gatsby build time. I can probably use a npm module like [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) to create the zip archives.

I'm not sure how to integrate the zip archives into the gatsby infrastructure. I could update `onCreateNode` or `createPages` to create the zips. should I write the zips to the public folder? can I store the zips as buffers on the gatsby node?

Comment: it looks like you know the answer... no time to PoC?